# How to fix hot-reload problem on a Flask application inside Docker?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want my flask application to run with hot reload inside docker container but if I change my app.py flask application to `app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')` instead of `False`, it raises the error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/app.py': '/app/app.py'

If I change back to `False`:

`app.run(debug=False,host='0.0.0.0')`

it will run, but without hot reload.

My Dockerfile is:

```
    FROM ubuntu:latest
    RUN apt-get update -y
    RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev build-essential locales
    RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8  
    ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
    ENV LANGUAGE pt_BR:pt:en  
    ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
    ENV FLASK_ENV="development"
    WORKDIR /app 
    COPY . /app
    VOLUME ["/app"]
    RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
    CMD ["app.py"]
```

and I run it using the command: 
`docker run -p 5000:5000 -v /Users/rodrigodmpa/Documents/IA/web:/app flask-app`

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things wrong with the Dockerfile. I think your immediate problem is the `VOLUME ["/app"]` line. You have copied the code statically into your image, and declared that containers running that image are exporting a volume at the `/app` location, then are launching the container with a bind-mount volume to the same location. There's likely some permissions issues where this ends up making the container no longer see the contents of `/app`. You don't need the `VOLUME` declaration, so ditch it.

Also: always put `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` in the same `RUN` declaration. If you don't, and then edit the packages installed, then by default Docker will cache layers from the previous command. That means you could be installing a package based on package definitions from a long time ago. It should look like `RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev build-essential locales`

Comment: Hi @wmorrell, thanks for the feedback! without the `VOLUME` declaration I would need to rebuild or restart the container every time I change my application.. that's why I'm using it.. but anyway, I tried removing it and running `docker run -p 5000:5000 flask-app` (without -v) and the hot reload doesn't work either.

Comment: @RodrigoDemetrio that's not how `VOLUME` in a Dockerfile works. Setting `VOLUME` makes that path available for _export_ from the container, and is used with the `--volumes-from` argument to `docker run`. If you want to hot-reload code, remove the `VOLUME` declaration from the Dockerfile, and _do_ use the `-v`/`--volume` flag to `docker run`.

Comment: Hi @wmorrell, tried that, still with the FileNotFoundError error